# How to cast object to a type without disabling type checking?

Tags: typescript

Both `as` and `<>` ignore type checking completely. I can use something like the following function to do the same while checking the type, but I was wondering if there's a built in mechanism to do the same, to reduce the amount of useless common functions (as it's a common construct in most languages)?

```
const cast = <T>(x: T) => x
```

To explain why this is needed - I'm passing an object literal to a generic function and I need to ensure that it is treated as a certain type, while also making sure I don't forget any properties.

Comment: `function <T extends {foo: 'bar'}>(a: T){}` ?

Comment: I would suggest using something like this, however, it turns properties into `unknown`: `const isObject = <T>(arg: unknown): arg is Record<keyof T, unknown> => !!arg && typeof arg === 'object' && !Array.isArray(arg);`

Comment: @Dimava I know how to do it with a helper function, but I was expecting there to be a built in method to do that as it's a common thing in other languages (i.e. reinterpret cast in C++ that ignores pointer types, vs a regular cast that will not let you cast to unrelated types)

Comment: Then it's `const foo: Foo = xThatExtendsFoo`

Comment: Are you maybe looking for [the `satisfies` operator](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-9.html#the-satisfies-operator)?  It would help if you'd provide a [mre] that we can test different possible solutions against.  Can you show examples where you use currently use something like `cast`?

Comment: @jcalz oh thanks didn't know about that one, it's very useful for some cases. Though not exactly what I was looking for here, unless I do `satisfies X as X`.

Comment: I'm getting syntax errors using it, I guess it's not implemented yet? Latest version of ts-node (10.9.1) is still on 4.8, and so are most of the other tools I'm using.

Comment: Does this question depend on a particular version of TypeScript?  If so you should mention that in the question directly.  Being stuck on TS4.8 doesn't seem dependent on ts-node (looking at docs it seems that it uses whatever version of TS you have installed, but what do I know, the question isn't tagged with ts-node so I'm not expecting to need knowledge of that to answer).  Do you want to [edit] the question with more clarity on requirements, and again, provide a [mre] that shows what you're trying to support exactly?  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

To cast a variable to a wider type, create a new variable of it:

```
interface Foo {
  a: number;
  b: string;
}
interface Bar {
  a: number;
}

const foo: Foo = { a: 1, b: '2' }
const notFoo = { a: 'string' }

// casting foo to `Bar` type, with assignability check
const bar: Bar = foo;

const notBar: Bar = notFoo;
//    ~~~~~~
// Type '{ a: string; }' is not assignable to type 'Bar'.
//   Types of property 'a' are incompatible.
//     Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'number'.(2322)
```